# Haskell implementing different behavior for types to increase code resue

Tags: haskell, abstraction

I am updating some code I have. I noticed a lot of repeated code, so I took that as a good sign that some abstraction was needed.

I have several functions that transition a State from one to another. The code to execute the transition is identical for every file.

**This:**

```
runOneTest :: Config -> Signal TestResult
runOneTest config = TestResult config <$> result
  where
    result = topEntity startingState inputSignal
    startingState = startS config
    inputSignal   = signal $ input config
```

What is not identical are the values in the Config Type or the TestResult.

```
data TestResult = TestResult { initConfig  :: Config
                             , endSt        :: St
                             }deriving (Eq)

data Config = Config { input  :: PIn
                     , startS :: St
                     }deriving (Eq)
```

More specifically the values that are different are the St(State) and the PIn(PortsIn). Those types can have different values attached.

**Example:**

```
data PIn = PIn { _clk   :: Bit
               , _reset :: Bool
               , _start :: Bool
               , _stop  :: Bool
               }
```

vs

```
data PIn = PIn { _in_1 :: Bit
               , _clk  :: Bit
               , _reset :: Bool
               }
```

I was trying to do that with classes but I am running into problems.

**Current:**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Abstract Area
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data TestResult = TestResult { initConfig :: (Transition t) => t
                             , endSt      :: (SysState s) => s
                             }

data Config = Config { input   :: (PortIn p) => p
                     , startSt :: (SysState s) => s
                     }

class (Eq s, Show s) => SysState s

class Transition t where
  runOneTest :: (Transition t) => t -> Signal TestResult

class Result r

class (Eq p, Show p) => PortIn p



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Stuff to define in each file
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

runOneTest' :: (Transition t) => t -> Signal TestResult
runOneTest' config = signal $ TestResult config st

data PIn = PIn { _clk   :: Bit
               , _reset :: Bool
               , _start :: Bool
               , _stop  :: Bool
               } deriving (Eq, Show)
instance PortIn PIn

data St = St { _cnt_en   :: Bool
             , _count_us :: BitVector 4
             , _stop_d1  :: Bool
             , _stop_d2  :: Bool
             , _count    :: BitVector 4
             } deriving (Eq, Show)
instance SysState St

st :: St
st = St False 0 False False 0

instance Result TestResult

instance Transition Config where
  runOneTest = runOneTest'
```

**The type of errors I am getting are:**

```
Couldn't match expected type `t1' with actual type `t'
  `t' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        runOneTest' :: Transition t => t -> Signal TestResult
      at ConvertedClashExamples\ClassExample.hs:50:16
  `t1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       a type expected by the context: Transition t1 => t1
       at ConvertedClashExamples\ClassExample.hs:51:31
Relevant bindings include
  config :: t (bound at ConvertedClashExamples\ClassExample.hs:51:13)
  runOneTest' :: t -> Signal TestResult
    (bound at ConvertedClashExamples\ClassExample.hs:51:1)
In the first argument of `TestResult', namely `config'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `TestResult config st'
```

**Original Full Source:** https://github.com/LambdaScientist/CLaSH-by-example/tree/master

**Note:** I looked answers to this question, but I did not find a good enough answer.

Comment: If you want more help you'll include code that can be loaded by other people including the imports required to load it. It looks like you're missing the quantifiers on your TestResult type: `data TestResult = forall t s. TestResult { initConfig :: (Transition t) => t
                             , endSt      :: (SysState s) => s
                             }`

Comment: `class Transition t where
  runOneTest :: (Transition t) => t -> Signal TestResult` should not duplicate the Transition constraint. Use `runOneTest :: t -> Signal TestResult`

Comment: Each file in the ClashByExample_Converted folder should be runable by itself in GHCI. I forgot to mention that. Thanks!

Comment: @glguy may have solved it. I will know for sure is a few.

Comment: @glguy If you want to add you comment as an answer I will mark it as correct.